# Julia no method matching copyto when assigning to matrix

Tags: julia

I want to write generic code that would work like

```
matrix = zeros(cols,rows)
indices = [1,2]
a[indices,1] .= some_value
```

when indices are a list but would also work like

```
matrix = zeros(cols,rows)
indices = 3
a[indices,1] = some_value
```

when there is only one index.
However, the `.=` only works with lists, while `=` only works with individual indices. E.g.

```
a[[1,2],1] = some_value
 ArgumentError: indexed assignment with a single value to possibly many locations is not supported; perhaps use broadcasting `.=` instead?
```

and

```
a[2,1] .= 1
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching copyto!(::Float64, ::Base.Broadcast.Broadcasted{Base.Broadcast.DefaultArrayStyle{0}, Tuple{}, typeof(identity), Tuple{Int64}})
```

Is there some way to make this code more agnostic to the type of `indices`?
So far I had no problem writing agnostic code that reads from `matrix` at `indices` but it turns out that writing is a problem.

Comment: In Julia, it is common to design a function `f(x)` that works on a scalar `x` and whenever the function is required to work on a vector `v`, we just do `f.(v)`. So, I don't see why this behavior is problematic at all. If you used MATLAB, for example, you can't do that and you have to define a new function to work on vectors or modify the function to check input dimensionality.

Comment: Also, in Julia if you want the function to behave totally different on vectors than on scalars, you can do that with **multiple dispatch**.

Comment: @alagris This seems like an XY problem. It is fine to write code that is agnostic with respect to type of vector (e.g. range, bitvector, static vector, regular vector, etc.), or with respect to numerical type. But the code should probably *not* be agnostic wrt whether something is a scalar or an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Julia, it is common to design a function `f(x)` that works on a scalar `x` and whenever the function is required to work on a vector `v`, we just do `f.(v)`. So, I don't see why this behavior is problematic at all. If you used MATLAB, for example, you can't do that and you have to define a new function to work on vectors or modify the function to check input dimensionality.

Also, in Julia if you want the function to behave totally different on vectors than on scalars, you can do that with **multiple dispatch**.

That said, you can use broadcasting in your case as below. The syntax `A[inds...] = X` is converted to `setindex!(A, X, inds...)`. So, you can use `setindex!.(Ref(A), X, inds...)` and it should work for scalars and vectors.

```
rows, cols = 3, 3
matrix = zeros(rows, cols)
some_value = 5

indices = [1, 2]
setindex!.(Ref(matrix), some_value, indices, 1)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 5.0  0.0  0.0
 5.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  0.0
 
indices = 3
setindex!.(Ref(matrix), some_value, indices, 1)
3×3 Matrix{Float64}:
 5.0  0.0  0.0
 5.0  0.0  0.0
 5.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
indices = [3]
```

instead of:

```
indices = 3
```

and it would work with `.=`. In any case, a good principle for Julia is type-stability i.e. to assign just one type to variables. Thus `indices` would better be assigned just a Vector{Int} and not also Ints. If multiple types are needed, multiple dispatch might be an option, like @AboAmmar commented.